# "What is the weather today?" or "How is the weather today?"

Tags: word-choice, phrase-choice, wh-questions

If I want to ask about the weather today whether is cold or hot, worm or cloudy or foggy, rainy or snowy etc. What should I choose of these two (or may be there's another way)?

> "**What**'s the weather today?"

or

> "**How**'s the weather today?"

What's the appropriate choice for the mentioned need?

Comment: To my ear, "what's the weather like today" sounds more natural than "what's the weather today".

Comment: @littleO Thank you.  Are you American or British?

Comment: I'm American, I probably should have mentioned that.

Comment: Interesting.  Thanks.  It would be helpful to see also a British point of view.

Comment: I'm also American. "What's the weather today" sounds fine to me.  It sounds like you're asking for yourself, rather than making idle conversation.

Comment: British here: would also say "what's the weather like today?" or "what's the weather _going to be_ like today?"

Comment: Compare "how's your steak|what's your steak", "what's your new car|how's your new car". "What" is asking for a description of what kind of thing it is, "How" is asking for an evaluation of its merits.

Answer (score 25):

Both can be fine.  While the first focuses more on the objective *description* of the weather, and the second focuses more on someone's subjective *opinion* of the weather, the answer can go either way, depending on how the listener chooses to *interpret* the question.

Examples:

> James: What's the weather out there?
>   Phil:  It's miserable.
>   James:  No, I mean *what's it like*?  Warm, sunny, rainy ...?
>   Phil:  It's hot, humid, and totally miserable.
>
> James:  How's the weather out there?
>   Phil:  Sunny, some clouds, relatively cool.
>   James:  So it's nice?
>   Phil:  Yes, it's nice.

For this reason, I wouldn't worry too much about it.  You can always clarify your question if you want to know something specific.

Comment: +1 because I *think* we're both singing from the same hymn-sheet here.

Comment: Phil seems like he's bad at understanding the thing you outlined in your answer...

Comment: @NicHartley  I assume that, at least in the first example, Phil is too focused on his subjective experience to comment on the objective experience.  :)

Comment: not familiar with that first usage in AmE. I have heard "what's the weather like?"

Answer (score 17):

They're both perfectly natural. Arguably some people might think the ***what*** version is more appropriate when the speaker is specifically interested in knowing what the weather actually ***is*** (or perhaps ***will be***, later in the day).

Conversely, the ***how*** version might be more likely if what the speaker wants to know is *how the addressee feels about the weather*.

Expanding on the above, I suspect the "frequency of occurrence" of the ***how*** version (relative to the ***what*** version) would be higher in the context of ***telephone calls***. If you're talking to someone who's far enough away that "their" weather is likely to be different to whatever you're currently experiencing, you'd have more reason to ask what they think of their weather.

But if you're talking to someone who's actually *with* you, you probably wouldn't be asking what the *current* state of the weather is (you can see as well as them whether it's raining or not). And if you're asking ***What*** is the weather [**forecast for**] today?, that would rarely be phrased using ***how***.

Comment: There’s also the sarcastic/joking “How’s the weather up there?” to comment on how tall someone is (or how’s the weather up there {on your high horse/in your ivory tower/etc.} ) I don’t think “what's the weather” would work as well in that context, because “how” sort of emphasizes the inaccessibility/distance from the speaker’s perspective.

Comment: Let's say you've just come back from a vacation, I would ask you: _"So what was the hotel like?"_. But can I ask you: _"How was the weather?"_ I mean does it sound natural to you? Or would you rather say _"What was the weather like?"_

Comment: I'm repeating myself, but ***They're both perfectly natural.*** Feel free to ask ***How was the hotel**?* if you prefer that phrasing. *Offhand*, I can't think of an example utterance where ***What was X like**?* can't be replaced by ***How was X**?* But my gut feel is there *might* be contexts where the ***How*** version doesn't work (or is less idiomatic). In some contexts, ***What was John like**?* could be seen as asking *What did he do (and/or how did he do it)?*, where ***How was John**?*  asks about his physical and/or emotional ***condition / health***.

Answer (score 8):

I agree with both the other answers about the relative usage of the two forms you've mentioned. I will add one more possibility:

Often when I'm deciding what to wear for the day I'll ask my spouse to look at his phone and tell me what his weather app says. In that case, I'll usually use some variation on

> What is the weather **supposed to be** today?
>   What is the weather **going to be (like)** today?

or just

> What's **the (weather) forecast for** today?

In this case, I'm not talking about the weather *right now* but rather the (expected) conditions throughout the day.

Answer (score 2):

To me "What is the weather today?" is a very unnatural sentence.  At least in my recent memory, I've never heard a native English speaker say that.

As others have mentioned, the *what* version conveys a more scientific tone, while the *how* version conveys a subjective tone.  As a result, I think you would be more likely to use *what* to discuss forecasts and *how* to discuss the current weather.  However, you will also hear "What's the weather like today?" and I would say this *like/what* pairing is semantically equivalent to *how*.

I'm an American English speaker (from California), so I would be curious to see if other people who use the phrasing "What's the weather today?" come from a different area, because it sounds so unnatural to me (though of course it's grammatically correct).

Comment: I grew up in California, though I've lived on the East Coast more than 20 years now, and find *what's the weather today* unexceptional. In my idiolect it's essentially equivalent to *what's the weather like today?* or *what's the weather forecast for today*? depending on context, as with a recent breakfast exchange with my roommate, with the blinds still closed: *Are you riding to work? / That depends; what's the weather today? / Rain again. / I guess I'm taking the Metro then. / No, the Metro is flooding. Take an Uber.*

Answer (score 2):

As an English man I have just come across this phrase in a foreign school teaching children English. I have to admit I have never heard anyone say or use the phrase, "What is the weather today ?". In England we would say, "What is the weather like today?" or " What is the weather forecast for today?". I hope that helps.