# The usage of "What weather is it today?"

Tags: expressions

Is it possible to ask "What weather is it today?" instead "What's the weather like?"

Comment: https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/174118/what-is-the-weather-today-or-how-is-the-weather-today

Comment: Does this answer your question? ["What is the weather today?" or "How is the weather today?"](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/174118/what-is-the-weather-today-or-how-is-the-weather-today)

Comment: *What weather is it today?* is "syntactically valid", but ***not idiomatic***. On the other hand, you *can* use the "existential **it**" construction to ask, for example, *What temperature is it today?*

Comment: I meant , can we ask 'What weather is it today?' . Is it right, if we speak about the structure of a sentence and grammar.

Comment: Like I said, it's "syntactically valid" (it doesn't break any grammatical rules). But ***in practice***, native speakers simply wouldn't normally say it. I can imagine an unusual contrived context where a competent native speaker *might* deliberately use that "non-standard" form, but for you as a learner, there's really no point in exploring some completely unnatural context that you'll never encounter in real life. For all practical purposes, *What weather is it today?* is ***not right - it's wrong!***

Comment: I bet you have understood very few of the comments under your question. Too bad a simple answer was not good enough.

Answer (score 1):

Let's be clear about what is idiomatic:

**What's the weather today?** Cloudy with a chance of rain.

**What's the weather like today?** Cold and snowy.

Both can be used conversationally or when speaking. This is not complicated and is a beginner question, which is fine.

**like** is now often use here though it is not needed. *like* is often used in questions where the answer is a description.

- What's he **like**?
- He's a **nice** man.

Rule for questions in English with words like what, when, where, how and the verb be

The order is:

**What** + [is or are] [subject: the weather] today?
What is your name? Same structure.
How is your sister.
Where is your car?
How were your exams this year?

Etc. Etc. Etc.

Comment: In the first example 'the weather' appears to be an abbreviation for 'the weather forecast'. I think that's why the sentence works.

Comment: @Jelila It does not matter for 1. [subject] can be "the weather" or "the weather forecast".